# Throws IllegalStateException when putting values to ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, servlets, illegalstateexception, concurrenthashmap

**Issues:**
Sometimes hit IllegalStateException when putting loginID and session into ConcurrentHashMap.

**Background:**
to avoid concurrently login, I save loginID with http session as ConcurrentHashMap into servlet context. 
Every success login, to check if loginID exists in ConcurrentHashMap in servlet context. If exist, invalidate the previous session and save the current session.

```
at com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionImpl.invalidate(HttpSessionImpl.java:302) 
at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.invalidate(SessionData.java:247) 
at com.ibm.ws.session.HttpSessionFacade.invalidate(HttpSessionFacade.java:200) 
at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.LoginCommand.doPost(LoginCommand.java:184)

doPost(...) {
    ServletContext application = session.getServletContext();
    Map<String, Object> loginMap = (Map<String, Object>)application.getAttribute("loginMap");
    if(loginMap == null) {
        loginMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    for(String loginID : loginMap.keySet()) {
        if(loginID.equals(request.getParameter("user_id")) {
            ((HttpSession)loginMap.get(loginID)).invalidate();
            break;
        }
    }

    //LINE 184. Here sometimes throws IllegalStateException
    loginMap.put(request.getParameter("user_id"), session);

    application.setAttribute("loginMap", loginMap);
}
```

Comment: Is this method threadsafe?

Comment: It is Http doPost method

Comment: What is your exception trace?

Comment: Which line throws this exception? My guess is the last one.

Comment: This line throws exception: 
   loginMap.put(request.getParameter("user_id"), session);

Comment: Full stack trace, including where it mentions your class.

Comment: ... and including where it mentions the *exception* and the message ...

Comment: I have edit the content and put the stack trace and the message.